# Printing list from JSON

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to list images from list of names in JSON, but when I run it, console in browser shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')
    at HomePage (bundle.js:1128:36)
    at renderWithHooks (bundle.js:40442:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (bundle.js:43204:17)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:44403:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:29392:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:29441:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:29501:35)
    at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:49243:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:48079:16)
    at workLoopSync (bundle.js:48016:9)
```

Here is my main App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import { NavBar, HomePage } from "./components";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {

    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);

    const handlePlayerHeads = async () => {

        const { data } = await fetch("https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/fabrykacraft.pl")
            .then(result => result.json());


        if (data !== undefined && data.players.list !== undefined) {
            setPlayers(data);
        }

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        handlePlayerHeads();
    }, []);




    return (
        <Router>
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <Routes>
                
                    
                <Route exact path ="/" element={<HomePage playerList={players} />} />

                
                
            </Routes>
            
        </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Also here's the HomePage (where is the problem showing):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useStyles from "./styles";



const HomePage = ({ playerList }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const urlStatApi = "https://example.com/api";
    var loaded = false;
    if (playerList !== null && playerList !== undefined) {
        loaded = true;
}


return (
    <div>
       
        <div className={classes.display} >
            {loaded ? playerList.players.list.map((name) => (
                <img className={classes.playerHead} src={"https://mc-heads.net/avatar/" + name + "/32/nohelm.png"} key={name} />
            )) : <p>Loading</p>}
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
)
}

export default HomePage;
```

I've also made sure that path to list in JSON is correct and printed out on console JSON to check if it fetches without problem.
EDIT: I added a null-check for loading, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: The component first renders with no data. Then data is fetched and it re-renders. Check in your component for null and return a loading div or something.